# How I can append records to an existing file that is already zipped without to unzip/decompress it first?

Tags: php, csv, zip

I need to export a large dataset into a csv using php:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open("myzip_".now().".zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addFromString('test.csv');

$item=100000000;

while($item>0){
  
  $f = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
  $array=[$item,time(),rand(),"item_".time()."_".rand()];
  fputcsv($f, $array);
  
  rewind($f);
  $csv = stream_get_contents($f);
  fclose($f);
  

  $item--;
}
```

What I want is to append the record in `$csv` variable in to the `test.csv` in my zipfile, without the need to decompress the file first. The reason why I want to do this because it will incrementally increase its size and may run out of disk space. Is there a way yo do so?

Comment: I doubt this is possible. But the underlying issue you have is another one: that you allow that file to grow in a strictly monotonous way. That rarely is a good decision for obvious reasons. So you actual question is not about how to add something to a compressed file, but how to prevent that file to grow indefinitely.

Comment: Sorry, not possible

Comment: In general, I don't think there is a good enough reason why this _should_ be possible. The resulting compression ratio would certainly be less good in the overwhelming majority of cases - ZIP is a dictionary-based compression algorithm, and it makes a huge difference, whether that methodology gets applied to one big piece of data - or to two pieces of data separately. Now compression ratios might not be _your_ main concern here, for your very specific use case - but that one wasn't what the developers of the algorithm had in mind to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe though I think it may7 be possible with other compression algorithms though.